# Server initiated backup

Tags: windows-7, linux, backup

I've read the most secure way to handle backups is to have the server initiate it and be un-writable to the client. This prevents encrypting viruses from getting your backups as well as your attached drives, which would be quite catastrophic.

Does anyone know of a way this can be achieved? I currently have a NAS running unRAID at home and several computers running windows 7/10 which are rarely, if ever, backed up.

Comment: I too face similar problem. I need to backup data from multiple computers to one place, but I can't let computers to have access to each others data. Preventing writes also make it secure to ransomware (this was the whole point for backups). For now I am using this ugly solution: On every PC I created user backup, grand him read access to directory I need to backup and share this directory. I use linux server for storing backups, here every 2 hours I run script that scan network, tries to mount \\HOST\$bacup for every host it finds and perform rdiff-backup. It's very ugly, but for now it works